# How unique is this generated key?

Tags: cryptography, random

I am building a small app. I want to generate a random and unique key for each user. If this thing takes off, I might have millions of users! [Coincidentally, this happening is about 1 chance in many millions! :) ]

I need a math person to vet my math here. Do I have this right?

A key will be something like:
X1b-7h4

Each character is random and can be up to 62 different numbers, based on:
. 0-9, a-z, A-Z (So 10 + 26 + 26 possibilities).
. the hyphen does not count (it is for readability)

Is this part right?
For each 3 characters (like "X1b") there are 238,328 possibilities
. as in, 62³

So, if the key is 6 characters it will be:
. 62^6 possibilities (56,800,235,584)

And so on:
. 9 characters is 62^9
. 12 characters is 62^12
. etc, etc

Do I have this right?

Important point: I am not checking each generated key to make sure it is unique, so I need a big enough key to make it (almost) safe to assume this is the case...

Thanks! :)

Comment: Yes you have it right.

Comment: Yes, you have the right idea.  The problem changes if you insist on certain conditions... such as not allowing 1 (one) ,l (lowercase ell), and I (upper case i) all as being allowed characters simultaneously since they look so similar, or if you insist on no repetition of characters, etc...  For what its worth, if the length of your ids isn't particularly important to you you can just use [uuids (Universally unique identifiers)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) or guids, though that may be killing a fly with a bazooka.

Comment: Chances are 99.9% that you mess something up and your keys turn out to be easily cracked with a bit of cleverness. Use a reputable and well-tested key generator.